# Disable all caching for iterating over huge querysets

Tags: python, optimization

Here is my code:

```
def new_badge(badge_classes=None, users=None):
    """
    Utility function for awarding a badge when a new one is added.
    """

    badge_classes = get_badges_classes() if badge_classes is None else badge_classes
    total = users.count()

    for i, user in enumerate(users.iterator()):
        t0 = time.time()
        flight_ids = []
        for flight in user.flight_set.order_by('date').iterator():
            flight_ids.append(flight.id)
            flights_before = Flight.objects.filter(id__in=flight_ids)
            for BadgeClass in badge_classes:
                badge = BadgeClass(all_flights=flights_before, new_flight=flight)
                badge.grant_if_eligible()

        print "-- %s" % user.username
        print "-- %.2f s" % (time.time() - t0)
        print "-- %.2f%% done" %(float(i) / total * 100)
```

There are 2700 objects in the `users` queryset, and over 500,000 flights. When I run this script, I expect it to take a really long time, but the problem is that it's using up more and more memory. After a few hours, the script stops with this error:

```
File "/Users/chris/Documents/flightloggin2/badges/models.py", line 361, in eligible
  c = countries.count()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in count
  return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 418, in get_count
  number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/sql/query.py", line 85, in get_aggregation
  return super(GeoQuery, self).get_aggregation(using)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 384, in get_aggregation
  result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
  cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

django.db.utils.DatabaseError: could not create temporary file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp98246.932828": No space left on device
```

How can I fix this? When I run the script, `top` tells me the python process that is running the script has 10G of memory, so I think it's something on python's end, not postgres, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: This doesn't look like a memory problem (to me).  It looks like you're running out of disk space.

Comment: This will probably run orders of magnitude faster and have fewer resource problems if you write it as a single SQL `SELECT` statement. Doing it with nested cursors is going to be slow and fragile.

Comment: This actually *is* a memory problem of sorts and definitely on postgresql's side. It is running out of disk space while trying to create a temp file.  Temp files are used to cache large volumes of data, in this case it's likely to be caching a very large result set.  The temp file is created under the main table-space for the DB so if there's a way to free up extra space on the partition then that may help.  Finding a way to reduce the result set that it's caching would also help.

Comment: ... Also it looks like this error is not occurring from within the code you've given here; it's inside `badge.grant_if_eligible()`.  The eligible method appears to be going back to the DB for more info.  Without seeing that code, it's not clear how much extra it's asking the DB to do.